# Archive type changed to Generic Xcode Archive and is not making ipa

Tags: iphone, ios5, archive, xcode4.4, ad-hoc-distribution

with the reference of this [Xcode has started making archives, not apps. How do I change it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126787/xcode-has-started-making-archives-not-apps-how-do-i-change-it-back) question and answer i have to change my "Skip Installation" flag but i am unable to find this flag. I am using xcode 4.4.1. 
Kindly help me how can I fix it?[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to project - build settings. In the search field type "skip". It will show you the Skip Install option in Deployment.

Comment: if you see under the build settings there are 4 options "Basic", "All", "combined", "levels". In my case "Basic" was selected when i selected "All" then Skip was available to me. Thanx

Comment: To be clear: set `Skip Install` to NO on your archive project, and YES to any sub-projects.

Comment: thanks TRedman: I've also faced with this issue after having added a project as dependency to another. I had to set Skip Install to YES foer the subproject in order to correctly create the .ipa file