# Generic Xcode Archive without libraries

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

When archiving my Mac OS application, I'm getting a "Generic Xcode Archive". I have read that this can be solved by setting **Skip Install** to **YES** on any static libraries but I have not added any static libraries. I have two targets and a few frameworks.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**:

This happens when I add the second target to my "main application" as either a target dependency or in "Copy Files". Does anyone know how to avoid this and still link the two projects?
The second target is a C command line tool.

Comment: Have you tried the approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407712/there-is-no-share-button-in-xcode-4-3-organizer#comment13442518_9409178?

Comment: Yes, with no luck. I ended up compiling the product and adding it to my primary target.

Comment: @SimonBS: You probably should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up compiling the product and adding it to my primary target.

It doesn't really solve the exact problem but it is somewhat of a solution.

As pointed out by Peter Hosey this is probably a bug.