# iPhone app publishing can't validate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to publish my new app but ran into a problem. After I archive and get the organizer screen with my app in archives tab. When I try to validate it, it gives me an error.

"Game app name"
does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.

I do not know what this error means or what to do. Can someone please help me out. Will appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a subproject with a static library. Make sure that **Skip Install** is set to Yes in the build settings of anything that is not your application.

Comment: can having my sprites on desktop cause this?

Comment: Not really. no. But it's a bad idea to have your project files lay in dozens of places anyway.