# Why do public headers make a multiple product bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, static-libraries

When archiving my current iOS project I faced the [multiple product bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle) problem.

Basically, this happens when Xcode fails to recognise your project as a single product bundle and thus is unable to present it as an iOS App Archive, which is what you submit to App Store.

In my case, the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318616/143378)  was removing all the Public headers of **some** of the referenced static libraries (changing them into Project headers).

This is bad because those headers are meant to be public for a reason.

Why is this necessary? Is this a Xcode bug or am I missing something? Why some static libraries need this and some don't?

And finally, Is there another way to solve this problem that doesn't require to change the header visibility?

Comment: I'm pondering the same question at the moment for my own framework/static library. Driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the answer he wrote himself?

> OK, answering my own question. Turns out it is an issue with dependent projects in XCode 4. If this happens to you, go through the Build Settings for all your dependent projects (e.g. static libraries) and make sure that the "Skip Install" option under "Deployment" is set to YES.

More detail here: http://flakasoft.com/developer-tips/xcode-4-bug-solution-for-archiving-build-with-static-library/