# Archive validation "does not contain a single-bundle application or contains multiple products"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit to the Apple app store. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle) and from there to [this](http://doronkatz.com/tip-your-app-name-does-not-contain-a-single-bundle-application-or-contains-multiple-products-please-select-another-archive-or-adjust-your-scheme-to-create-a-single-bundle-application/), but I cannot fix the problem in Xcode organizer archive validation. It says "does not contain a single-bundle application or contains multiple products".

In the second link above it says: "you may in fact have either not done the steps above properly, or there is another static library you missed out on adding the flag install skip : YESor move copy header files to project from public/private." I don't understand that "move copy header files part", is it asking me to move it or not to move it, or move it from where to where?

Inspecting the archive I only find one .app and one .app.dSYM, but I do have a folder of /usr/local/include/ withe some header files there? But I don't understand why it's getting in there. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out for sub-projects I've included (static project) I need to move all headers from public and private to project. That at least quench the warning.