# Xcode 5: Where is "Copy Headers" in the Build Phrases section?

Tags: xcode5, bundle

"Click Build Phrases and under Copy Headers, move all of the Public and Private entries to the Project section."

I'm stumped. I'm trying to follow this final step, but when I go to the Build Phrases tab in Xcode, I see, specifically, four things:

-> Target Dependencies (1 item)

-> Compile Sources (146 items)

-> Link Binary With Libraries (10 items)

-> Copy Bundle Resources (101 items)

none of these things match "Copy Headers." I'm very noob, so if someone could help, I would really appreciate it. Thanks everyone.

(I'm ultimately trying to solve the "does not contain a single bundle" error, and this is in the tutorials)

I'm literally directly referring to [Archiving project in Xcode incorrectly creates multi-application bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle)
Everyone is talking about "Copy Headers." Where is it?

I have two targets for my project: my .app, and objectivechipmunk

Answer (score 0):

So, after many hours I finally figured out how to prevent the "does not contain a single bundle" error. You need to *not* skip install in your main .app file. You should only skip install in your other files, specifically for me, objective chipmunk.