# After archiving my project, I don't see "Submit to the iOS App Store." in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, cocos2d-iphone, organizer

[I'm trying to publish a Cocos2D iOS game to the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html) (please see the link), but it seems that the "Submit to the iOS App Store." option is not there when I click the "Distribute" button in Organizer. I only see the "Save Built Products" and "Export as Xcode Archive" options. I'm using Xcode 5.1, and I have build my project for release mode, as well as checked to make sure I'm using the iOS Distribution code signing identity. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the chipmunk target in Cocos2D had to have the "Skip Install" option set to yes: [Archiving project in Xcode incorrectly creates multi-application bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206536/archiving-project-in-xcode-incorrectly-creates-multi-application-bundle).